Showing Schauder Basis for $L^p([0,1])$
The question is given in the following way:

Let $1\le p<\infty$. For $t\in [0,1]$, let $x_1(t)=1$, $$x_2(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & 0\leq t \leq 1/2\\
      -1 & 1/2\leq t\leq 1\\
\end{array} 
\right. $$
and for $n=1,2,...,j=1,...,2^n,$ $$x_{2^n+j}(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      2^{n/p} & (2j-2)/2^{n+1}\leq t \leq (2j-1)/2^{n+1}\\
      -2^{n/p} & (2j-1)/2^{n+1}\leq t\leq 2j/2^{n+1}\\
       0 & otherwise
\end{array} 
\right.$$
Then, the Haar System $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...\}$ is a Schauder basis for $L^p([0,1]).$

Can anyone please suggest the steps to say it Schauder Basis of $L^p([0,1])?$

Here are two steps.

If $g \in L^p$ satisfies $\int g (t) x_j(t) dt=0$ for all $j$, then $g=0$ a.e.
Indeed, the indicator of every interval of the form $[0,j/2^k]$ is a linear combination of $x_j$'s. The end points of these intervals are dense in $[0,1]$, and therefore $\int_0^x g(t) dt =0$ for all $x$.

Obtain a unique representation.



If $f= \sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j x_j$ then $\int f(t) x_{j'}(t) dt =  c_j \int x_{j}(t) x_{j'}(t) dt$. By construction, $\int x_j (t) x_{j'}(t) dt=0$ if $j\ne j'$. This gives you both an expression and uniqueness for $c_j$'s.

Now look at $g=f-\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j x_j$, and apply part 1 to conclude it is equal to $0$ a.e.


